# 408 Request Timeout error in Opencart admin

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

When I does save from OpenCart admin. We get Request Timeout error.

> Request Timeout
>
> Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client.
>
> Additionally, a 408 Request Timeout error was encountered while trying
> to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I think, It is working fine with `http://` URL. but, testing with `https://` url. So, It does happen.

is this SSL related problem?

How can i resolved?

Comment: Is there anything else in error.log ?

Comment: if you have doubt with ssl first check without ssl. or check your config file is correct. also check have any error. or have any permission issue. if not solved share config.